# Copy a file to the root directory of the image file

Tags: assembly, x86-64, bootloader

I'm working on Mac. I've tried [Mtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/intro.html). I couldn't even install it cause it shows a bunch of errors I can't handle(trust me this is not for me).

What I want to do is simply copying a normal file to a fat12 Img file.
something like you can do with Mtool.

```
mcopy -i floppy.img mornal.file
```

How I can do this besides using the Mtool. 
This is a file I want to write in Img file.

```
    ORG 0xc200
    MOV AL,0x13
    MOV AH,0x00
    INT 0x10    

fin: 
    HLT
    JMP fin
```

I've added `JMP 0xc200` after boot sector has done its works and tried just adding filename and the code where the fat12 file system allows it to locate(0x2600 and 0x4200: where FAT12 loads meta data and data itself).

```
t:
    TIMES       0x2600-0x512 DB 0   
    DB          "TEST    sys"       ;8bytes file name : meta data
    TIMES       0x4200-0x2611 DB 0  ;2611 = 2600 + file name(11) 
    ORG         0xc200              ;data
    MOV         AL,0x13
    MOV         AH,0x00
    INT         0x10    
fin: 
    HLT
    JMP fin     
done:       
    TIMES       0x168000-(done-t) DB 0
```

This is BIOS parameter block and rest of my code.

```
    JMP     entry
    DB      0x90        
    DB      "MyOS    "  
;BIOS Parameter Block
    DW      512     
    DB      1       
    DW      1       
    DB      2       
;End of BIOS Parameter Block
    DW      224     
    DW      2880        
    DB      0xf0        
    DW      9       
    DW      18      
    DW      2       
    DD      0       
    DD      2880        
    DB      0,0,0x29    
    DD      0xffffffff  
    DB      "MyOS-Vol   "   
    DB      "FAT12   "  
    TIMES       18 DB 0     
entry:
    MOV     AX, 0           
    MOV         SS,AX
    MOV         SP,0x7c00 
    MOV         DS,AX                       
    MOV         AX,0x0820       

    MOV         ES,AX           

    MOV         CH, 0           
    MOV         DH, 0           
    MOV         CL, 2           
readloop:   
    MOV         SI, 0           
retry:      
    MOV         AH, 0x02        
    MOV         AL, 1           
    MOV         BX, 0           
    MOV         DL, 0x00        
    INT         0x13            
     JNC        next            
    ADD         SI, 1           
     CMP        SI, 5
    JAE         error
    MOV         AH, 0x00
    MOV         DL, 0x00
    INT         0x13            
    JMP         retry 
next:
    MOV         AX,ES
    ADD         AX,0x0020
    MOV         ES,AX 
    ADD         CL, 1
    CMP         CL,18
    JBE         readloop
    MOV         CL, 1
    ADD         DH, 1
    CMP         DH, 2
    JB      readloop 
    MOV         DH, 0
    ADD         CH, 1
    CMP         CH,CYLS 
    JB      readloop  
    JMP     0xc200
fin:
    HLT                 
    JMP     fin         
error:      
    MOV         AX, 0
    MOV         ES,AX
    MOV         SI,msg
printloop:
    MOV     AL,[SI]
    ADD     SI, 1           
    CMP     AL,0
    JE      fin
    MOV     AH, 0x0e        
    MOV     BX, 15          
    INT     0x10            
    JMP         printloop
msg:
    DB      0x0a, 0x0a      
    DB      "load error"
    DB      0x0a            
    DB      0 

maker:      
    TIMES       0x01fe-(maker-start) DB 0
    DB      0x55, 0xaa
```

But it shows error when I assemble it.

```
error: program origin redefined
```

I guess it's becuase I've used `ORG 0xc200` after using `ORG 0x7c00` in bootsector. But I thought it would be okay since I am writing it on right place(0x2600, 0x4200). 
I thought this is what IPL does. jumps to program where it's located and the program should have been allocated on memory.

In short, the question is

- How can I place this code on right place in bootloader image file?
- I saw someone doing this kind of thing using `mount` and finder but How can I do this programmatically(becasue I should create a Makefile for this prosedure)?

btw can I do this with `dd`?

Comment: I've corrected some math problem, still same :(

Comment: Have you tried `hdiutil mount floppy.img` ?

Comment: According to [this blog post](http://saumilsmac.blogspot.ca/2009/10/mtools-for-mac-os-x.html), building mtools for OSX just needs `./configure LIBS=-liconv` and then it goes fine.

Comment: Does your disk image have a BIOS Parameter Block?

Comment: @Michael Petch I just tried it but it give me this error `hdiutil: mount failed  -  there is no available file system'

Comment: @Michael Petch yup It does

Comment: What does this command return `file floppy.img` ?

Comment: @MichaelPetch it returns `floppy.img: x86 boot sector, code offset 0x4e`

Comment: Okay, that suggests to me that your BPB is actually not correct/not in the right place. Can you show us your asm code from the top of your bootloader to a few lines after your BPB? The only thing your output says is that it did find the disk signature 0xAA55 at the end of the first 512 bytes of first sector.

Comment: With a proper BPB you should see something like: `x86 boot sector, code offset 0x5b, OEM-ID "MYOS 1.0", sectors/cluster 2, root entries 240, sectors 5760 (volumes <=32 MB) , sectors/FAT 9, serial number 0x54428e71, unlabeled, FAT (12 bit)`

Comment: There is a part of me that thinks your BPB exists, isn't correct, but somehow 4 bytes smaller than it should have been. This is an educated guess (I wouldn't bet money on it)

Comment: I think your right, check out the rest of code.

Comment: I'm assuming you assemble using NASM with something like `nasm -f bin -o outputfile.bin` where outputfile.bin is the name of your boot sector image. I'm curious what `file` says about that bootsector. I'd be curious to know what `file outputfile.bin` says where the file you specify is simply the 512 byte bootsector file created directly by NASM.

Comment: Yes, that's what  I show you on my comment. I did `file bootl.img` this is the whole outcome of `nasm -f bin bootloder.asm -o bootl.img`.  The BPB and rest of code is showing without rest of zeros(bootl.img is filled with zeros after 512 byte). And I need to combine the program in my question with this bootl.img.

Comment: Your BPB actually appears okay. It is definitely for a 1.44mb floppy. Strange thing was I took your boot sector binary (using the nasm command above) then ran these 2 commands: `dd if=/dev/zero of=floppy.img bs=1024 count=1440` to create a zeroed out disk image, then used `nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin` (where boot.asm was your bootsector program). Then did `dd if=boot.bin of=floppy.img conv=notrunc` to put the bootsector on the disk. I was then able to mount it with `hdiutil mount floppy.img`.

Comment: My understanding is that your second program you wish to place into the root directory of the disk image. Correct?

Comment: Yup, that's correct. That's the thing I really want to do

Comment: In my last long comment with the DD commands I just made some edits. The first version I put was typed up incorrectly. It would be curious to know what happens if you use my method to create the disk image.

Comment: But as its stands I don't see your bootloader code properly searching the root directory of a FAT file system (even if you mounted the image and were to copy your program in).

Comment: Wow, my heads about to explode!!! I've tried your DD commands and few other things like  `sudo mount -t msdos floppy.img ./test`  and tried [other's code](http://fisnikhasani.com/building-your-own-bootloader/)(if I `file thiscode.img` also give me `boot.img: x86 boot sector, code offset 0xba
`). But all of this dose not WORK!!   `dd` gave me an error `no mountable filesystems`.

Comment: If you don't mind could you please give me a fine example that dose not show any error to mount on mac ox. btw thank for all your effort to answer this question :)

Comment: I gave you the exact commands I used to assemble your bootloader and then build a disk image which was then mountable (on OS/X) with hdiutil.